# can't git push to remote server

Tags: git

I don't know if this is the right site to ask this, but it's my most used. I'm trying to use the free no.de service to host my Node.js app. I create the machine and setup my ssh keys correctly, and follow all the steps to the letter. but the final step won't work. It has me push the git repository, but I get this error:

> Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey). fatal: The
>   remote end hung up unexpectedly

Any ideas as what might be the problem? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Seems the server does not like your SSH public key.

Comment: Yes it can. I'm doing it all the time.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i copied it directly from git's ssh key. there was alot of extra text in it. what should a key look like?

Comment: Always try to diagnose ssh problems using `ssh -v` first. What happens when you try that?

Comment: 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. - That's what i get

Answer (score 0):

As you are on windows, you'll either need to install cygwin or Putty to get an ssh-client to do the above suggested "ssh -v"-equivalent. Of these Putty might be the easier solution on windows, it does also have an ssh-key handler utility (Pageant)
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Your problem seems to relate to your key not being used properly in this case, do you get asked for the pass-phrase at any point?